# Getting the output of a script in Matlab called from R

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to call a very simple script in Matlab from RStudio. However, whenever I run the following code, without getting any error, it will return 0 to me. Would you please let me know how I can call Matlab scripts in R and get their **outputs**?

```
run_matlab_script("C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Sum.m", verbose = TRUE, desktop = FALSE, splash = FALSE, 
display = TRUE, wait = TRUE, single_thread = FALSE)
```

Note that to use the above function, I am using "**matlabr**" package in r. Moreover, my simple script in Matlab includes the below code:

```
b=1+2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does "run_matlab_script" come from? Have you tried option 3 from [this](https://mandymejia.com/2014/08/18/three-ways-to-use-matlab-from-r/) link?

Comment: @Ben, they mentioned the `matlabr` package, which leads to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matlabr/ and https://github.com/cran/matlabr/blob/master/R/matlab_script.R#L119

Comment: @Ben, thank you for your reply. I looked at the third option. If I am not wrong, it requires me to code my Matlab script in R. However, my original script in Matlab is very complicated and I do not want to code it in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matlab::run_matlab_script` uses `system` to call matlab. As of today, that function (current commit is [c01d310](https://github.com/cran/matlabr/blob/c01d3105770ad6331387dea772db10b917d015c5/R/matlab_script.R#L119)) looks like:

```r
run_matlab_script = function(
  fname, 
  verbose = TRUE, 
  desktop = FALSE,
  splash = FALSE,
  display = FALSE,
  wait = TRUE,
  single_thread = FALSE,
  ...){
  stopifnot(file.exists(fname))
  matcmd = get_matlab(  
    desktop = desktop,
    splash = splash,
    display = display,
    wait = wait,
    single_thread = single_thread)
  cmd = paste0(' "', "try, run('", fname, "'); ",
               "catch err, disp(err.message); ", 
               "exit(1); end; exit(0);", '"')  
  cmd = paste0(matcmd, cmd)
  if (verbose) {
    message("Command run is:")
    message(cmd)
  }
  x <- system(cmd, wait = wait, ...)
  return(x)
}
```

Noteworthy (to me) is that `run_matlab_script` includes `...` in its formals, and passes that unchanged to `system`. *In fact*, its help documentation specifically says that is what it does:

```
#' @param ... Options passed to \code{\link{system}}
```

Because of this, we can try to capture its output by looking at `system`. From [`?system`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html),

```
  intern: a logical (not 'NA') which indicates whether to capture the
          output of the command as an R character vector.
```

which suggests that if you change your call to

```r
ret <- run_matlab_script("C:/Users/XXX/Desktop/Sum.m", verbose = TRUE, desktop = FALSE, 
                         splash = FALSE, display = TRUE, wait = TRUE, single_thread = FALSE,
                         intern = TRUE)
```

you will get its output in `out`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. However, the above code returns an empty character. To make sure that my Matlab file is not the origin of the problem, I tried both the following script and function file. But still, it returns an empty character!  script file: `b = 2+1` or function file: `function b = Sum() b = 2 +1 end` @r2evans

Comment: `system("ls", intern=TRUE)` returns a character vector, so the logic is sound. If nothing is being returned, that suggests that perhaps matlab is not printing anything. I'm not a matlab user so this is speculation, but ... some languages are more chatty on the console (interactive) than when called programmatically (such as here), perhaps your matlab script needs to explicitly print something? (Idk)

Comment: As stated here (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/272876-how-to-make-return-value-in-for-loop), "MATLAB does not need a return statement to return a value. To return a value you simply need to list it as an output argument of the function."  Even when I use the function format, it does not return anything in r. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't know matlab, but in most languages, the concepts of `return` and `print` can be significantly different. I think you're going to need to work exclusively on the matlab side of things, since I suspect that the R side is not the (only/first) problem.

Comment: I ended up using R.matlab package and it works perfectly for me. Thanks anyway.